# What are the steps I need to take to add nice java code formatting to my blogger/blogspot blog?

Tags: java, html, formatting, blogger, blogspot

I'm looking for a sequence of steps to add java code formatting to my blogspot blog.

I'm really looking for a dummies guide - something so simple a cleaner could follow it if they found it on a piece of paper on the floor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use [Google prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) script (StackOverflow uses it also), here you can find a good guide for using it with blogger:

- [Source code high-light in Blogger](http://sunday-lab.blogspot.com/2007/10/source-code-high-light-in-blogger.html)

You have other alternatives like [SyntaxHighlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/), [here](http://urenjoy.blogspot.com/2008/10/publish-source-code-in-blogger.html) also you can find a guide to use it with blogger (or any other blogging software)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Syntax Highlighter, also on google code, Java is one of the many supported languages

http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/

here is a post from Scott Hanselman on how to install and use: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BestCodeSyntaxHighlighterForSnippetsInYourBlog.aspx

Answer (score 2):

How about SyntaxHighlighter?

SyntaxHighlighter is a fully functional self-contained code syntax highlighter
developed in JavaScript.

Support:

ActionScript3 Bash/shell ColdFusion C# C++ CSS Delphi Diff Erlang Groovy
  JavaScript Java JavaFX Perl PHP Plain Text PowerShell Python Ruby Scala SQL
  Visual-Basic XML

http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter - 
                home page